# How to get pod IP address in helm template for hostAlias:

Tags: kubernetes

Im trying include podIP in Helm template using status.PodIP in hostAlias section. But hostAlias didn't accept status.PodIP and expect for a proper IP address.

How to put podIP in /etc/host through helm template.

Im trying include podIP in Helm template using status.PodIP in hostAlias section. But hostAlias didn't accept status.PodIP and expect for a proper IP address.

How to put podIP in /etc/host through helm template.